# Sequitur on multiple strings

Tags: python, context-free-grammar

I would like to use Sequitur (and in particular its very nice implementation in the Python scikit package) to infer a CFG from a large number of strings (“sentences”). Sequitur expects a single string as entry. Of course I can incluse my strings into BEGIN and END symbols and concatenate them into a single long string without ny loss of information. But in that case the structure Sequitur will find will cross sentence boundaries, and this is not what I want.

How can I make Sequitur look only inside sentences and produce no rule the projection of which includes a BEGIN symbol followed by an END symbol? (Except for the first rule, that would be an umbrella for all sentences…)

Example: If I have sentences "The boy eats the apple" and "The girl sleeps", and I replace words by their POS tags ("a" for article, "n" for noun, "v" for verb) I get "anvan" and "anv". If I merge them including B (BEGIN) and E (END) symbols I get the string "BanvanEBanvE". When I supply this string to Sequitur I get

```
0 → 1 2 E 1 E 
1 → B 2 v
2 → a n
```

where the first rule has E symbols but no B symbols, and the second one a B symbol, an intermediate symbol (essentially the noun phrase ART+NOUN) and a v.

What I would like would be

```
0 → B 1 E B 2 E
```

etc. so that the rest of the grammar has only sentence-internal rules. In our simplistic example, it would be

```
0 → B 1 E B 2 E
1 → 3 v 3
2 → 3 v
3 → a n
```

Is there a way to achieve that without altering the algorithm's code? If not, is there some other (implemented) algorithm that allows to obtain exactly that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using sksequitur.Mark to place a delimiter between different strings.

```
from sksequitur import Grammar, Parser, Mark
parser = Parser()
parser.feed('anvan')
parser.feed([Mark()])
parser.feed('anv')
print(Grammar(parser.tree))
>> 0 -> 1 2 | 1
>> 1 -> 2 v                                          anv
>> 2 -> a n                                          an
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have a solution using nltk. I tried with sksequitur but without success. You may try to combine both.
Here is what I have:

```
import nltk

Corpus=['B','a','n','v','a','n','E','B','a','n','v','E','B','a','n','E']

nbSentences=Corpus.count('B')  # Counts the nb. if sentences (B for "BEGIN" and "E" for END)

print('Nb. of sentences: ',nbSentences)

C='C -> '+'T '*nbSentences  # The corpus C is made of nbSentences "Tokens" 

core_grammar=  """
 T -> BEGIN S END
 S -> NP VP | NP
 PP -> P NP
 NP -> A N
 VP -> V NP | V
 A -> 'a'
 N -> 'n'
 V -> 'v'
 BEGIN -> 'B'
 END -> 'E' 
"""

# Generate the grammar:
gramm_str=C+core_grammar
print('grammar string: \n',gramm_str)

# Parsing:
simple_grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring(gramm_str)
parser = nltk.ChartParser(simple_grammar)
tree = parser.parse(Corpus)

#print(list(tree)[0]) # simple output
list(tree)[0].pretty_print() # for a pretty_print
#list(tree)[0].draw() # draw in w window
#list(tree)[0] # to draw tree in jupyter notebook
```

The result:

[image]
As you can see, all sentences are processed, each producing its own tree (no crossing between sentences)
Now, if you have millions of sentences... It might be a problem.

Best regards,
Stéphane

Comment: Thanks Stéphane, but where did you got the core grammar from?

Comment: It could come from sksequitur. In your first example: NP <--> rule 2, VP <--> rule 1  and S <--> rule 0. So, in principle, you could use sequitur to create the core grammar.  May be not that easy...